# Jssor full length slider is not working in opera 9.64 version?

Tags: javascript, slider, jssor

Jssor full length slider is not working in opera 9.64 browser version. even jssor web site also not opening properly

Comment: Do you mean full width slider?

Comment: Would you please send me opera 9.64 install package? jssor@live.com thanks!

Comment: Yes full Width Slider, Download opera 9.64 using http://fs37.filehippo.com/9997/aa837fdde3df4c149b0a9e7525004df6/Opera_964_en_Setup.exe

Comment: jQuery doesn't support opera 9.6.4. Please use no jquery version demos-no-jquery/full-width-slider.source.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery doesn't support opera 9.6.4. Please use no jquery version demos-no-jquery/full-width-slider.source.html